# Is a selectbox option visible or hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, nightwatch.js

I'm about to test a little dropdown selectbox with nightwatch/selenium.
While testing I experienced that the options of the selectbox seem to be visible (for the test runner) even tho it hasn't been clicked.
I have very few skills in HTML therefore I'm not sure if this is default behaviour or my test is kind of broken.

**Testcode:**

```
var urlToOptionsPage ='chrome-extension://dafanlbggefkfnbekjceijjhgcancpik/html/options.html';

module.exports = {

  '[Options Page UI] - project list': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url(urlToOptionsPage)
      .pause(500)
      .waitForElementVisible('#projects', 5000)
      .assert.value('#projects', 'BWK')
      //.click('#projects')
      .waitForElementVisible('#projects > option:nth-child(1)', 5000)
      .end()
  }
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="projects" id="projects">
  <option value="BWK">BWK</option>
  <option value="DMG">DMG</option>
  <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
</select>
```

**Test-Result:**

```
 ✔ Element <#projects> was visible after 52 milliseconds.
 ✔ Testing if value of <#projects> equals: "BWK".
 ✔ Element <#projects > option:nth-child(1)> was visible after 35 milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome it isn't, however in firefox at least it is. So my answer would be; its browser dependent. You can test by running:

```
// jQuery required
var optionsVisible = $('option').eq(0).is(':visible');
alert(optionsVisible); //alert if options are visible or not
```

or take a look [here](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/yOKjQd).